# Image inside custom Spinner is blurry

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-spinner

I made a custom spinner with an image inside to be showed as a spinner default visual:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXLHl.png)

but the arrow image is very blurry, and I can't adjust in order to stay clean as the image below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hYEZ.png)

here's my spinner's layout:

```
 <Spinner android:id="@+id/sMeasPla"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
 android:background="@drawable/tk_spinner_background"
 android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_separator_bottom"/>
```

My selector (tk_spinner_background):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/tk_spinner_background_pressed"
           android:state_pressed="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/tk_spinner_background_default"
           android:state_focused="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/tk_spinner_background_default" />
 </selector>
```

My spinner background (tk_spinner_background_default):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
         <layer-list>
             <item>
                 <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid
                            android:color="@color/transparent" >
                        </solid>
                    <stroke
                        android:width="3dp"
                        android:color="@color/gray_light" >
                    </stroke>

                    <padding
                        android:left="@dimen/padding_edit_text_left">
                    </padding>

                    <corners
                        android:radius="10dp"   >
                    </corners>
                 </shape>
             </item>
             <item
                 android:top="5dp"
                 android:right="10dp"
                 android:bottom="5dp">
                 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner_arrow_default"
                         android:gravity="top|right" />
             </item>
         </layer-list>
     </item>
 </selector>
```

I don't have any methods in Bitmap like in an imageView (layout_width, layout_height, scaleType, etc) to change the image size...

can anyone tell me a way to have more control with the image size in a bitmap or other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the poorly use of the drawable folders... I had all images inside the same folder (drawable-hdpi)

Don't ask me why, but the devices (I tried in 5 different devices) wouldn't re-size the image correctly in this specific case... (probably because I couldn't define the size)

When I separate every image correctly with the specific size in the corresponding folder, the problem was solved, and the image appeared correctly...